# DELETE method that integrates with a Lambda Function (AWS)

Tags: javascript, api, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I will start this by saying that I know this is probably the worst JavaScript implementation you will see but I am required to use it for academic purposes.

I am required to make a static website and deploy an API Gateway for my application with GET, POST, and DELETE methods that integrate with a Lambda Function.

My GET and POST functions are functioning well but the problem is with the DELETE.

```
    <script>
        var url = 'The API endpoint';
        var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
        
        submitBtn.addEventListener('click', getDetails);
        function getDetails(){
            var mail = document.getElementById('mail').value;
            var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
            if(mail == '' || firstName == ''){
                alert("Please submit valid data!");
                return;
            }
            var params = '{"Item": {"email": "' + mail + '", "firstname": "' + firstName + '"}}';
            httpDeleteAsync(url, params, processResponse);
        }
        
        function httpDeleteAsync(url, params, callback){
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
                    callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            console.log(params);
            console.log(JSON.parse(params));
            xmlHttp.open("DELETE", url);            
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            xmlHttp.send(params);
        }
        
        function processResponse(response){
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = response;
        }
    </script>
```

The console doesn't display any errors, but I get a null response on my page when I try to delete.
Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE #1**
I am starting to think that the problem is with the Lambda function not sure if I am right though.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    //console.log(event['body-json']);
    var tableName = 'Customers';
    var params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item : event['body-json'].Item
    }
    
    
    // docClient.put(params).promise().then(res => res).catch(err => err);
    
    docClient.delete(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to delete item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("DeleteItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was treating the DELETE as the opposite of POST hence their processes being similar in code but I was mistaken. The DELETE had more in common with GET. So by thinking with that mindset I was able to solve the problem. Down bellow are the adjusted codes.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    <script>
        var url = 'YOUR API'
        var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
        
        submitBtn.addEventListener('click', getDetails);
        function getDetails(){
            var mail = document.getElementById('mail').value;
            if(mail == ''){
                alert("Please submit a valid email!");
                return;
            }
            var params = 'email=' + mail;
            httpDelAsync(url, params, processResponse);
        }
        
        function httpDelAsync(url, params, callback){
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
                    callback(JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText));
                }
            }
            console.log(params);
            xmlHttp.open("DELETE", url + "/?" + params);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        
        function isEmpty(obj) {
            for(var key in obj) {
                if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        
        function processResponse(response){
            //console.log(response);
            if(!isEmpty(response)){
                document.getElementById('firstNameLabel').innerHTML = response.Item.firstname;
                document.getElementById('mailLabel').innerHTML = response.Item.email;
                document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('firstNameLabel').innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById('mailLabel').innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "DELETED";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**Lambda Function:**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var tableName = "Customers" // Put your Table Name Here

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(event.email)
    
    var params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Key: {
            email: event.email
        }
    };
    return docClient.delete(params).promise().then(res => res).catch(err => err);
    
};
```

There is a slight problem with the response of the DELETE but it works fine so I left it as it is.